# Inserting Date into INPUT field using jQuery

Tags: jquery, datetime, input

I have 4 INPUT fields for month, day, hour, minute.

```
<input type="text" id="month" name="month" value="" />
   <input type="text" id="day" name="day" value="" />
  <input type="text" id="hour" name="hour" value="" />
  <input type="text" id="minute" name="minute" value="" />
```

I am trying to get CURRENT time using JS and insert into each field using jQuery.

Can you help me to work out the right code to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

meh... for what it's worth: http://jsfiddle.net/V3J8c/1

```
$("#month").val(months[new Date().getMonth()])
$("#day").val(new Date().getDate())
$("#hour").val(new Date().getHours())
$("#minute").val(new Date().getMinutes())
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. Nice tool. Really nice.

Comment: @jonnypixel You're quite welcome! I absolutely love this tool, and i learned about it from SO too.

Answer (score 9):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var now = new Date();
   $("#month").val(now.getMonth() + 1); //Months in JS start from 0
   $("#day").val(now.getDate());
   $("#hour").val(now.getHours());
   $("#minute").val(now.getMinutes());
});
```

See this [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more information on the `Date` object.

Comment: `now.getDate()` should probably be `now.getDay()+1` ;)

Comment: No it shouldn't. `getDay` returns the current day of the week (e.g. 4 currently). `getDate` returns the day of the month (e.g. 11 currently).

Comment: @jonny pixel - There should be a button to the left of my answer so you can mark it as the accepted answer. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date(),
    currDay = date.getDate(),
    currHours = date.getHours(),
    currMonths = date.getMonth() + 1;
    currMinutes = date.getMinutes();

$("#day").val(currDay);
$("#month").val(currMonths);
$("#minute").val(currMinutes);
$("#hour").val(currHours);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date();
$('#month').val(date.getMonth() + 1);
$('#day').val(date.getDate());
$('#hour').val(date.getHours()); // This will be based on a 24-hour clock.
$('#minute').val(date.getMinutes());
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date